# Custom image attribute not saving programmatically in Magento2

Tags: product-images, image, programmatically, magento2.2.3

I have created a custom image type attribute. And trying to set image from code. But it is showing random behaviour.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
        $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');      
        $mediaPath=$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();


$id = '123'; // YOUR PRODUCT ID;
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id); // Load product object



            $sku = $product->getSku();

            $imageAssign = $mediaPath.'catalog/product/image.png';

            if (file_exists($imageAssign )) {                   
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageAssign, array( 'my_flipper_image' ), false, false);
                $imageset = $mediaPath.'catalog/product/'.$sku[0].'/'.$sku[1].'/image.png';
                $product->setMyFlipperImage($imageset)->save();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the issue was I have migrated Magento 1 to Magento 2. So i Had to save all products once. And the script was working correctly.

However, it did not saved my product with custom attribute in admin. I managed to set it via Import CSV